# Regularization by inf-convolution

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a n.v.s. and let $\varphi: E \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ be a convex l.s.c. function such that $\varphi \not\equiv +\infty$. Let$$\varphi_n(x) = \inf_{y \in E} \{n\|x - y\| + \varphi(y)\}.$$

1. Do we have that $\varphi_n(x) \le \varphi(x)$ for all $x \in E$, all $n$?
2. For every $x \in E$, is the sequence $(\varphi_n(x))_n$ nondecreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, simply plug in $y = x$.
2. Yes, since $n||x - y|| + \phi(y) \le (n + 1)||x - y|| + \phi(y)$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x, y \in E$.